# Launch Flutter app using any hardware button click like volume up

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, mobile, automation

```
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
 import android.content.Context
 import android.content.Intent
 import com.example.sample.MainActivity

  class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() { 
      override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED == intent?.action) {
        val activityIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context?.startActivity(activityIntent)
    }
   }
}
```

In flutter app , using native code i am successful to launch the app after rebooting the mobile phone using that code in Kotlin but now i want to make the run using the hardware button like volume up or down or any else.Please help me using that approach or any other approach.The app idea is like that the blind person can easily open the app using the hardware button.